# Why my Telegram bot periodically goes offline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, telegram-bot

I have Telegram bot that listens for incoming commands from my app users. It runs under Sidekiq worker. But from time to time it goes offline and I need to start Sidekiq worker again. I just can't understand why it happens, there are no errors in Sidekiq logs. And where to look to find a problem?

Here is part of code from my TelegramInitWorker

```
require 'telegram/bot'
class TelegramInitWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: 5, :queue => :default
  Sidekiq::Logging.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG

  TOKEN = Figaro.env.telegram_token


  def perform
    logger.info 'Things are happening.'
    logger.debug "Here's some info: #{hash.inspect}"

    Telegram::Bot::Client.run(TOKEN) do |bot|
      bot.listen do |message|
        if message.from.username
          # here my stuff
        end
      end
    end    
  end
end
```

Comment: How much time for example? and secondly , i don't know ruby BUT I know that if you use `webhooks` method (setting webhook on telegram) then telegram will call your code, but if you do not use webhooks and use `long polling` method then your code MUST read updates from  Telegram. OK , but problem is if your code takes long time to wait for telegram in `long polling` method it may be gets `time out`.It means your code will STOP.

Comment: @TickTock Time is absolutely different. It can work for a week, or it can stop every few hours. I don't use webhooks.

Comment: so I recommend a scheduler which will run your code periodically(like `cronjob`s and so on) . Because scripts have time out s or if it doesn't have timeout, server may go down unexpectedly .

Comment: @TickTock but here is one problem it's impossible to start more then one telegram at once. and with cron I can't be sure that previous telegram is offline.

Comment: Dear friend, IMHO dealing with webhook is more comfortable than request based message. But if you insisted on `long polling` you should use such methods and ways to handle messages. AND each update that you receive has `update_id` . it is unique an increases. you can save your updates in Database and before saving check its `update_id` . in this manner it doesn't matter one or two or three calls of your code is running simultaneously.